# How to test get request on flask server using curl?

Tags: python, curl, get

I'm building a flask server that connects to a database, and I want to test if the GET requests work. However, I don't know how to send request data using curl.

When I enter

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

I get back the data I need, but `'/'` doesn't require any request data. 
But how do I use curl to send request data? Specifically, 2 strings.

For instance,

How could I test something like this with curl?

[image: example]

Comment: The URLs for curl are no different than the URL you enter into the browser. You just have to put quotation marks if they contain special characters.like `&`. Are you aware how query strings in HTTP URLs work?

Comment: @KlausD. Not exactly, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan, you need to request the proper `route` and pass the additional information in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Try:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/stream?name=Alan`